# Getting RGB color range for specific colors

Tags: c#

I need to get the RGB color ranges of some basic colors. ex Red color is between RGB(a,b,c) to RGB(x,y,z) like wise or using its Hue value.Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Could you pick where the red component is higher than both green and blue?  The problem with your request is that it would most likely be subjective to the rest of your application's colour scheme whether something should be considered red or not.

Comment: Where is your code? Did you try something at least?

Comment: This question does not make any sense.

Comment: You can for example look all named colors from the set you consider to be basic and define ranges from its defined RGB values (for example to cover whole spectrum).

Comment: Pretty hard logic to implement, as @Matthew mentioned because it is subjective. Do you already have your ranges defined? What about fringe cases like Pink... Its own color or a red? Regional differences where most shades of blue are green? Red green colorblind users?

Comment: Bhagya, you may have to experiment with this because your requirement doesn't seem as something that is common in development. So I would suggest that you would need to look at a color palate, see where RED starts and ends for you and see what the RGB values are and do likewise for all the other colors that you need to identify. It is gruntwork unfortunately.

Comment: Thomas how do I define the range for specific color

Comment: You are going in a cricle: You ask about specific color ranges for specific colors but don't know what a specific color is. __You have to decide__ it for yourself or look for standardized palettes. See [here for example](http://www.workwithcolor.com/red-color-hue-range-01.htm) or here for [hues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anyone can answer this in a convincing way as it is all based on the opinion of the person answering. *What do you really consider Red ?*

Consider **G = 0** and **B = 0**, now start increasing R from **0** step by step. People would argue, is **(100, 0, 0)** a valid red for you ? Or **(150, 0, 0)** is the start range for you ? You really need to test this yourself.

The below is not scientific at all, it is only based on my opinion:

I would consider Red starting from **(160, 0, 0)** going up to **(255, 0 0)**.

Also, When **R = 255**. I would consider any value **(R= 255, G = g, B = b)** where **g > b** as Red. Until you reach **(g = 200 and b = 200)** when it starts actually being white.

But when **b > g**, you'll get a color that may be considered a variation of red until certain range.

Conclusion: There is no correct answer for this. You really need to test it out and check what best match your requirement.

Comment: thank you very much. Is there a way to get this range using Hue value

Answer (score 0):

Here is a javascript approach to come up with an array of rgb values between two rgb values.

```
const lightestColor = 'rgb(204, 224, 245)';
const darkestColor = 'rgb(0, 102, 206)';
const length = 5

const colorArray = this._interpolateColors(
      lightestColor,
      darkestColor,
      length
    );

// interpolate between two colors completely, returning an array of rgb values
  private _interpolateColors(color1, color2, steps): string[] {
    const stepFactor = 1 / (steps - 1);
    const rgbArray = [];

    color1 = color1.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
    color2 = color2.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);

    for (let i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
      const color = this._interpolateColor(color1, color2, stepFactor * i);
      const string = color.join(', ');
      rgbArray.push('rgb(' + string + ')');
    }

    return rgbArray;
  }

  // Returns a single rgb color interpolation between given rgb color
  // based on the factor given; via https://codepen.io/njmcode/pen/axoyD?editors=0010
  private _interpolateColor(color1, color2, factor): number[] {
    if (arguments.length < 3) {
      factor = 0.5;
    }
    const result = color1.slice();
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      result[i] = Math.round(result[i] + factor * (color2[i] - color1[i]));
    }
    return result;
  }

console.log('colorArray. -->', colorArray);
```